# Is it possible to create a url link shortcut using Python, under Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to generate some shortcuts to specific websites using Python. Is it possible for me to do so under Ubuntu? Say If I'd like to create a shortcut to Stack Overflow in Home folder. How can I achieve that using Python?

Comment: Ubuntu probably has nothing to do with your question. Are you asking how to generate hyperlinks with python? Output to your desktop, maybe?

Comment: `print(url)` is the best I can come up with based on the information in the question.

Comment: @mwm314 Yeah, I was doing research on this and I found a package going this for window so that's why I included Ubuntu in the question. I'm sorry if that's confusing. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
with open('StackOverflow.desktop', 'w+') as f:
    f.write("""[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to                     Stack Overflow                 
Type=Link
URL=http://stackoverflow.com/
Icon=text-html
Name[en_US]=StackOverflow
""")
```

It will create a shortcut on Ubuntu to StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks I believe that's what I'm looking for.